# LuaLaTeX and algorithm2e

Tags: luatex, unicode, incompatibility, algorithm2e

The algorithm2e package seems to be not compatible with LuaLaTeX. For example, compiling the following code produces an error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Output of lualatex:

```
...
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.778 \renewcommand{\@algocf@procname}{Proc
                                       �dure}%
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

Has someone an idea how to fix that? I have a lot of algorithms typeset and do not want to switch to another package just because of LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The Package is not in UTF-8 format. If you open it and save it back in UTF-8 format it works (for me). To try, please copy `algorithm2e.sty` in the same directory, open it with an editor that can save it back in UTF-8.

Comment: @Andy. That works too. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: @Andy: converting to utf8 will help with lualatex but then you will probably get wrong fix names with pdflatex + an 8bit-option of `inputenc`. Using non-ascii chars in a sty is simply a bad idea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. It does not even _really_ work for Lualatex. ProcÈdure does not seem to be quite right when you have to use French. But while you are at it, should one only use ascii and save in UTF-8 or does that not matter so much?

Comment: My version use `procédure` which is ok for french. A sty should be pure ascii and it doesn't matter how you save it as the result will be the same. ascii chars are encoded identically in utf8, ansinew, latin1 etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem cannot be reproduced anymore.

Comment: @Werner please don't do that. The problem has appeared again.

Comment: @Trylks: You're only 3+ months late for that request... :-| The same answers holds as is listed below. I've also sent in a request to the [discussion mailing list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/README).

Comment: Why was this question closed? I am also getting same error with lulatex, using TL 2015.  How could an error from using a package in TL be off topic?

Comment: I also don't think it should be closed, since this problem occurs in overleaf.

Answer (score 10):

algorithm2e.sty contains (at least) two non-ascii chars (é in procédure), but the file is 8bit encoded so it is not a valid utf8 file. You (or the author) should replace the é by `\'e`.

Comment: @Peter: Unfortunately there are several other usages of `é` in that file, so I would try to use search-and-replace. Please don't forget to post a email to the author and mentioning this. It should be fixed for the next release.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. Substituting all accents solved the problem. I will send an e-mail to the author. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next release. Thanks for all your help!